# How much RAM does a Ubuntu 16.04 machine need to handle a 4TB ZFS volume?

Tags: 16.04, memory-usage, zfs

I am building a backup server with a 4TB ZFS volume.

I have found various guides for ZFS on Solaris and BSD which recommend 1GB of RAM for each TB of disk.

How much RAM does ZFS on Ubuntu 16.04 need, per TB of disk?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the rule of thumb is that 1GB of free memory (or more) is recommended. The more memory you have improves performance as it helps improve cache performance.  The amount of disk storage does not determine how much memory you need.  If you enable de-duplication then you need generally far more memory, I've heard that 5x more memory is required for de-dup.

Comment: You need a minumym of 1GB of RAM per TB of storage, *on top of what is needed for the OS to run*.

Comment: @Rinzwind can you write your comment as an answer with a source?

Comment: @ColinIanKing can you quote a source for your assertion that "The amount of disk storage does not determine how much memory you need."?

Comment: Source is personal experience. We did tests a couple of years ago on what we wanted to when replacing our servers. The option for a ZFS volume we discarded since it was too pricey compared to a google cloud instance.